# How to register an ec2 instance to AWS ELB without ec2 id ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is there anyway to register an ec2 in a elb without knowing the instance id only the dns name ?

I want to have a dns record point to a emr cluster that lives on a vpc

Comment: Your script will have to discover the instance id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AWS CLI [aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/register-instances-with-load-balancer.html) command, you must provide the following arguments

> --instances (list)
>
> The IDs of the instances.

The registration of an ec2 instance can only be done through the ec2 instance ID

If you only know your dns name you can find out the instanceId by running the following

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=dns-name,Values=<your_duns>"  --output text --query Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId
```

That will at least give you the instance Id for your ec2 instance so you can use it for the other command.

You should even be able to pipe the 2, I did not try but something like this should work

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=dns-name,Values=<your_duns>"  --output text --query Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId \
xargs -I {} aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name <name> --instances {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I cannot proced with this cloud formation as I want to. is there a way to point a dns record to an EMR master host ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cannot register or de-register EC2 instance programmatically without the instance ID. Instance ID is mandatory if you are doing the process programmatically.